# The best practice is to pass an argument in the method

Tags: c++, c++11

I have `map` class:

```
class map final
{
public:
    explicit map(const size_t capacity = 4);
    map(const map &copy) = delete;
    ~map();
    map &operator=(const map&) = delete;
    void add(std::string str);
private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> m_impl;
};
```

Method `void add(std::string str);` by default calls a copy constructor as I got. So I can use `map.add(std::move(str));` to call a move constructor. I have written the `main` function to show how I understand it:

```
int main()
{
    map m;
    std::string str = "test";
    m.add(str); // Copy
    m.add("test"); // ?
    m.add(std::move(str)); // Move
    m.add(std::move("test")); // Move

    return 0;
}
```

In comment I wrote a version of constructor that I expect... Is it right? And what constructor will be called in `m.add("test");`?

**How should I change my method signature to call a copy constructor for object that doesn't support a move and a move constructor for others? Including `const` objects**.

**P.S.** I am learning C++ only and just trying to get how does it work.
**P.P.S.** In the `add` method `std::move()` isn't called.

Comment: `std::move` doesn't move.  It just casts its argument to an rvalue reference.

Comment: `And what constructor will be called in m.add("test");?` Two words: "implicity converted". That's because `std::string` has a constructor that accepts `const char*`.

Comment: @HenriMenke, thank you, seems I have understood now.

Comment: @DimChtz, I have read about it now, thank you very much!

Comment: Aside: Unless the `add` function either moves the argument somewhere else (like a class member) or needs to modify the argument just for its own purposes, it should be declared `void add(const std::string& str);` so that no copy or move is ever needed at all to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    map m;
    std::string str = "test";
    m.add(str); // Copy
    m.add("test"); // Implicit call to std::string(const char*) ctor
    m.add(std::move(str)); // Move
    m.add(std::move("test")); // You shouldn't do so. You cast a literal to rvalue here.

    return 0;
}
```

To use copy or move constructor depending on the object capabilities, you should use *perfect forwarding* technique. Like this

```
template <typename T>
void add(T&& str);
```

Comment: @Шах: In StackOverflow, we usually thank people who answer us by upvoting them and/or accepting their answer. If you have something beyond a thank you as a comment on the answer, go right ahead and write it.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a character array that, after some transformation, turns into an argument to `string`'s implicit constructor, so the whole expression is regarded as a (temporary) rvalue of type `std::string`. What do you mean by 'doesn't call'?